# config.xml prevent "Open With" dialog android

Tags: android, xml, cordova

I wrote a phonegap app, the issue I am having on Android is when I click any link that is  it goes to the link in the app but it also opens the "Open With" dialog.  This is an annoyance. How can it be shut off?  I tried changing my config.xml file  tags but still not getting anywhere?

I tried

```
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

But get I the following dialog:

[image: Open With Dialon on Android]

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd have to write some java code to ensure that an app is installed and send the intent directly to it. I'm not sure if this is possible with just phonegap html/xml

Comment: i found another way but its a hack  it would require changing all anchor tags to span tags. i use jQuery classes to trigger all my events anyway but there has to be someone who's run into this before

Answer (score 0):

For those who run into this.  It can be fixed if you are using a hash href and using the classes to fire the events in jQuery.  I simply removed the href attribute for all anchor tags in the app and this fixed the issue.

```
<a href="#" class="btn">

if(android){
    $("a").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("href") == "#"){
            $(this).removeAttr("href");
        }
    });
}
```

turns into this:

```
<a class="btn">
```

also if we have an href with an id like #collapsable_id

```
if(android){
    $(document).on(evt, 'a', function(e) {
        if($(this).attr("href") != undefined && $(this).attr("href") != "#"){
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
    });
}
```